# How to adapt the jQuery dialog width to mobile browsers?

Tags: css, jquery-ui-dialog

I use jQuery dialog as pop-up form in my web application (ASP .NET MVC, bootstrap css style). When I open the web application in a mobile browser the dialog does not adapt to the display width. It possible to style the dialog for mobiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it's easy. All I have to do is set the width property of dialog as "auto" .

width: "auto"

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting new width?

```
// Returns width of browser viewport
var w = $( window ).width();
```

---

```
// Returns width of HTML document
var w= $( document ).width();
```

---

```
$( this ).css( "width" = w );
```